# Fatal error redeclare function when using wordpress widget twice on same page

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I get this error message in wordpress when I use the same widget twice on the same page:

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare buildURLArray() (previously declared in content.php:128) in content.php on line 128**

The correct content shows up in the first container, the second contains the error message above.

Here is the code, I shortened it, just left the structure:

/functions.php:  -> contains the widget

```
<?php
require_once( __DIR__ . '/functions/content.php');
require_once( __DIR__ . '/functions/content_special.php');

function arphabet_widgets_init() {}
add_action();

function wpb_load_widget() {}
add_action();

class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function widget() {
       $result=getContent();
    }
} 
?>
```

/functions/content_special.php:

```
<?php
function getContent(){
   $content = api();
   }
?>
```

/functions/content.php:

```
<?php

function api(){

    function buildURLArray () {}

    buildURLArray();
 }

?>
```

It works perfectly when I use the widget only once on the page.

When I use "function_exists ()" to avoid the error, I get a strange result. The result of the firt widget shows up twice. Then the result of the second..

Does anybody know where the problem could be? Maybe because of the "require_once()", or maybe because of the function within the class "wpb_widget extends WP_Widget"??

THX!

Comment: Declaring the function buildURLArray() in the function api(), cause it to be "redeclared" each time you call api() and declaring a function in a function is usally not a good practice. The solution here is to simply put it out of api()  
If you can't do it, could you complete your question with more details about this buildURLArray function and why it's required that its code is within the api() function ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Flinth! The problem was the function within a function. Now it works.

Comment: You're welcome ! Glad to helped you :-)